# Can I add one permission to many files at the same time?

Tags: command-line, git-bash

I am using Git bash on a Windows 7 system.

I have a directory with 20 files in it.  They have various permissions, but they are all missing w for the group.

I want them all to have w for the group and would like to change them all at the same time.  That is, I want to just add w for the group to the existing permissions.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `chmod` command.

Something like (untested):

```
chmod -R +w {dirname}
```

or

```
chmod +w *.ext
```

See the excellent [online bash documentation on ss64](http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html) which gives you an interactive tool for getting the correct permissions.

Comment: Actually, "chmod g+w" is closer to what OP requested.